# Floor Tile Texture Grout Setup

Tags: texturing, materials

I am trying to make a render of a house in which the supplier gives the image texture of the tile for the Flooring.

I am trying to understand how to best go about it as for now, my efforts have almost proven to no avail.

The image texture of the tile I get has no grout.

I have tried to add that with photoshop but looks washed out.

Currently, I tried it combing a brick texture and an image texture and the results are as you see in the link.

Please see what I am currently able to achieve.

You will see there the image texture I started from as well as the outcome picture of the floor I would like to make and render.

**Desired render outcome for pavement tiles**
[image: reference]

**My current outcome with *Brick* node and image node attached to it**
[image: rendered image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9w6x.jpg) is one more image and the used tile texture.

Any advice is very helpful I have been going crazy with this trying to understand how to make this as photorealistic as possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Actually, it would help to see your node setup for the floor material. Do you use a bump map, a normal map, or some displacement for the grout? And add a word or an image about the mesh topology. Is the floor just a plane or has it gaps for the grout? How does the UV map look like?